# Create CMake file from Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I have finished a project developed in Visual Studio 2013 (Windows) using OpenCV. Now, my manager told me he needs the code files and the CMAKE file.

I'm reading this documents:

- https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/
- http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

but I don't understand  properly and I don't know if they are what I need...

I can explain a little bit more my project:
My project has:

- main.cpp
- Some .cpp created by myshelf.
- Some .h created by myshelf.
- I use OpenCV libraries (lib, dll, ...)
- I use Vimba libraries (lib, dll, ...).

I have never worked with CMAKE files... Could anyone lead me about how create this file/s?? I'm really missed...

THANKS in advance!!!
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Read this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was useful but I have a problem Vimba libraries doesn't work with find_package...
I have code files, and libraries (dll, lib). 
How can write the proper lines for include this vimba libraries??
THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve create the makeFile. It's working properly in Windows. I execute cmake and from the code files it create the visual studio project properly and it works fine.

BUT when I try to execute the make command in LINUX I get errors :S:
*In function ..... error: 'infinity' des not name a type const auto....
*.... error: 'infinity' was not declared in this scope
*.... error: 'infinity' was not declared in this scope
*.... error: 'infinity' was not declared in this scope

The line where is the problem is this one:

```
const auto infinity = std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity();
```

It's a line from this project: https://github.com/soimy/munkres-opencv/tree/master/src

I think the problem is defining a infinity limit... Could anyone lead me to solve this problem?

THANKS!!!